# Netcat [nc] listen grep ip and disconnect

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

Is there a way to `grep` the IP address of the inbound connection and disconnect after a timeout?

If I do

```sh
nc -vv -l -p <portnum>
```

it's connected forever.

```
$nc -h
[v1.10]
connect to somewhere:   nc [-options] hostname port[s] [ports] ... 
listen for inbound: nc -l -p port [-options] [hostname] [port]
options:
    -4          Use IPv4 (default)
    -6          Use IPv6
    -c shell commands   as -e; use /bin/sh to exec [dangerous!!]
    -e filename     program to exec after connect [dangerous!!]
    -A algorithm        cast256, mars, saferp, twofish, or rijndael
    -k password     AES encrypt and ascii armor session
    -b          allow broadcasts
    -g gateway      source-routing hop point[s], up to 8
    -G num          source-routing pointer: 4, 8, 12, ...
    -h          this cruft
    -i secs         delay interval for lines sent, ports scanned
    -l          listen mode, for inbound connects
    -n          numeric-only IP addresses, no DNS
    -o file         hex dump of traffic
    -p port         local port number
    -r          randomize local and remote ports
    -q secs         quit after EOF on stdin and delay of secs
    -s addr         local source address
    -t          answer TELNET negotiation
    -u          UDP mode
    -v          verbose [use twice to be more verbose]
    -w secs         timeout for connects and final net reads
    -z          zero-I/O mode [used for scanning]
port numbers can be individual or ranges: lo-hi [inclusive];
hyphens in port names must be backslash escaped (e.g. 'ftp\-data').
```

I'm trying but I get no result.

My `netcat` is dated. The `nc` version number is 1.10

**EDIT**

@VictorLee gives me some alternatives. I made a thing.

Here there's a **little server script that listen and logs every new different access**.

If someone want to use or modify I put the code below

```
#!/bin/bash


unset PIDTMP; rm -rf tmplog.log 2>/dev/null

while true; do
    if [[ "$PIDTMP" == "" ]]; then
      nc -vv -l -p <YOURPORT> > tmplog.log 2>&1 & PIDTMP=$!;
    fi

    if [[ "$PIDTMP" != "" ]]; then
      if [[ -f tmplog.log ]]; then
        thisip="$(cat -v tmplog.log 2> /dev/null | tr -d '\0' | grep -aiv "failed" | grep -ioE -m2  "\\[([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}\\]" | tail -1 | sed 's/^.\(.*\).$/\1/')" 2> /dev/null
        #uncomment if u want output to screen
        #if [[ "$thisip" != "" ]]; then cat tmplog.log 2> /dev/null; fi;
      fi

      if [[ "$thisip" != "" ]]; then
        kill $PIDTMP 2>/dev/null
        wait $PIDTMP 2>/dev/null; unset PIDTMP;
        
        if [[ "$(grep -rnw log.log -e "$thisip" 2> /dev/null)" == "" ]]; then
          echo "$thisip" >> log.log
        fi
        unset thisip
      fi
    fi

    sleep 2
done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
nc -vv -l -p <portnum> >>/tmp/nc.log 2>&1 & sleep <timeout>;kill -9 $!
```

If you want to get the only connection ip, could run this `grep -oP "(?<=Connection from \[)[\w\.]*(?=])" /tmp/nc.log`, the one line is:

```
nc -vv -l -p <portnum> >>/tmp/nc.log 2>&1 & sleep <timeout>;kill -9 $!;grep -oP "(?<=Connection from \[)[\w\.]*(?=])" /tmp/nc.log
```

First collect the `nc` log to nc.log and force kill the `nc` progress until the time out, then get the connection ip by `grep`.

Comment: It works good, but there's a way to store the input to a variable and then kill the process. I tried ```grepped=$(nc -vv -l -p <portnum> 2>&1 & pid=$! && sleep <timeout>)``` but no result

Comment: Go VictorLee you'r the one. Save me!

Comment: Nice, You could try to find the way which could get the only client ip by `grep -oP "some pattern" /tmp/nc.log`.

Comment: MMMmmm @VictorLee "Nice, You could try to find the way which could get the only client ip by grep -oP "some pattern" /tmp/nc.log". I was saying to make a while loop but good in this way

Comment: So @VictorLee I think that's the only one way. Because if I put it in a subshell like this ```var=$(nc -vv -l -p <portnum> >>/tmp/nc.log 2>&1 & sleep <timeout>)``` then i can't take out the pid to kill. Or I have to create a file that stores the pid and it became all so difficult. P.S. Your things are only oneline :)

Comment: You could get the pid by `var=$(nc -vv -l -p <portnum> >>/tmp/nc.log 2>&1 & echo $!)`, and then execute `sleep timeout` for sleep and then kill the process by `kill -9 $var`. Is it what you look for ?

Comment: "You could get the pid by var=$(nc -vv -l -p <portnum> >>/tmp/nc.log 2>&1 & echo $!), and then execute sleep timeout for sleep and then kill the process by kill -9 $var. Is it what you look for ?" -> it's what i was looking for VOTED YOUR ANSWER